# ¿Cómo puedo cargar una biblioteca desde un CDN a Angular y usarla sus métodos?

Tags: javascript, angular

Necesito cargar la biblioteca

```
<script src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"></script>
```

desde el archivo `index.html` de mi sitio web de angular. Y necesito utilizar métodos de esta biblioteca desde uno de mis componentes.

En mi componente lo mando a llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
Mercadopago.setPublishableKey(key);
```

Pero me genera el error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/carrito.component.ts(274,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Mercadopago'.
```

Esta biblioteca **siempre** tiene que cargarse por medio del CDN. ¿De qué manera puedo utilizarla en mi componente?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el orden de tus scripts?

Comment: por favor muestrame una captura del componente ***carrito.component.ts*** para revisar la línea ***(274,5)***. Por otro lado es posible que necesites registrar esa nueva librería en tu ***app.module.ts***.

Comment: ¿lograste solucionarlo?, yo también tengo el mismo problema con otra librería y no logro solucionarlo...
saludos.